# React Native setState not re-render

Tags: react-native

I'm making a game for university project. I could not figure out why it's not re-render the screen when I use setState() for status, but it does when I use for fool. If I use console.log(status) It was altered after the setStatus.

```
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({ astrounauts: 0, research: 0, money: 0, publicity: 0 });
    const [fool, setFool] = React.useState(false);

    const acceptCard = (index) => {
        let statusAux = status;
        statusAux.astrounauts += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.astrounauts;
        statusAux.research += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.research;
        statusAux.money += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.money;
        statusAux.publicity += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.publicity;
        //no re-render... =C 
        setStatus(() => statusAux);
        //it does trigger re-render, not working without that.. this is dumb
        setFool(() => !fool);
        
    }
...
              <View style={styles.cardsOptions}>
                    <Swiper
                        cards={cards}
                        renderCard={(card =>
                            <Card card={card} />
                        )}
                        onSwipedRight={(cardIndex) => acceptCard(cardIndex)}
                        onSwipedLeft={(cardIndex) => rejectCard(cardIndex)}
                        //  onSwiped={(cardIndex) => { console.log(cardIndex) }}
                        onSwipedAll={() => { console.log('onSwipedAll') }}
                        disableBottomSwipe={true}
                        disableTopSwipe={true}
                        outputRotationRange={["-10deg", "0deg", "10deg"]}
                        cardIndex={0}
                        backgroundColor={'#18191A'}
                        stackSize={100}
                    >
                    </Swiper>
                </View>
```

Comment: Erick, see my recent edit on my answer... I think this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your state to a function.  the setState callback accepts the value itself, not a callback that returns the value.  You need to change:

```
setStatus(() => statusAux);
```

To:

```
setStatus(statusAux);
```

In addition to that... you are mutating the original object, you need to create a new object for React to detect the change.  You can do using the spread operator
like this:

```
let statusAux = {...status};
```

Comment: Thx you a lot. The:
 `let statusAux = {...status};`
worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to do this, Don`t need to use "()=>"

```
const acceptCard = (index) => {
        let statusAux = status;
        statusAux.astrounauts += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.astrounauts;
        statusAux.research += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.research;
        statusAux.money += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.money;
        statusAux.publicity += cards[index].acceptCardStatus.publicity;
        //no re-render... =C 
        setStatus(statusAux);
        //it does trigger re-render, not working without that.. this is dumb
        setFool(!fool);
        
    }
```

Comment: Sorry not have motioned it, but it was my first try. It does not work as well without the setFool

Comment: Okay no problem , did you check your console is there any other error or not ?

Comment: In console it worked. The status was right. What solved the problem was the
`let statusAux = {...status};
`